# Filtered list in js lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

Hi i have a list **component.get("v.TotInfo")** of type custom object list **Total_Order__c[]** and i want to get filtered list in js. Previously i  was doing this computation in apex.

```
    list<Total_Order__c> TOD1  = [SELECT  id,Order_Date__c FROM Total_Order__c WHERE 
     CALENDAR_YEAR(Order_Date__c) >= :lastYearVal AND Order_Date__c<=:system.TODAY()];
```

How to acheive this in js. I am using the sample code below.

```
<aura:attribute name="TotInfo" type="Total_Order__c[]" />

var today = new Date();
alert('today '+today.getFullYear());
var year = today.getFullYear();
var lastYearVal = year - 1;
for (var i = 0; i < TO.length; i++) {
 if (TO[i].Order_Date__c  <= today.getDate() && TO[i].Order_Date__c  >= lastYearVal) {
                          alert('check');

                   }
               }
```

Comment: please clarify on more,  my understanding is you would like get the records of based on the today condition, i am assuming you need use aura:iteration in component or loop in JS and add have filter condition

Comment: Is your problem with the date matching part (to nearest day?) or the filtering of an array part?

Comment: I have updated the question with sample code which i am doing now.